# C# Lower Math.Infinity

Tags: c#, math-functions

how can I change the Mathf.Infinity to make the Raycast length be something like 0.1 Meters?

```
// Fire a ray through the scene at the mouse position and place the target where it hits
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, mask)) {
    newPosition = hit.point;
    positionFound = true;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of trying to change Mathf.Infinity itself, the more sensible solution here should be changing the `... out hit, Mathf.Infinity ...` into `... out hit, 0.1f ...`.

Comment: Then you'll need to set the `maxDistance` bigger. Maybe take an example on your game map, like a point and a mouse position that you know should trigger this behaviour. Then Debug.Log the point and the mouse position `Vector3`s, check their actual positions and see what number should you set as distance.